# I am looking for a vxml (voicexml) parser in python language

Tags: python, parsing, ivr, vxml, freeswitch

I am looking for a vxml (voicexml) parser in python language. Need to use the parsed vxml tags and interact with freeswitch to run IVR. Can anyone help me with any kind of opensource vxml parsers?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't any standard XML parser enough? You could just write a quick wrapper to get the elemenents you're interested in (although xpath will also do that for you).

To verify correctness, the VXML schema / definition should be enough (as long as your chosen XML parser supports them)

If XML parser is too low level, let us know what do you expect from that kind of library.

Comment: I was looking for something which would give me the vxml tags along with their defined attributes (differ for each tag) and which can easily be embedded in a python system. If any such open source system is available then it can be of great help.